# way to close hidden excel applications? VB6 classic VB VBA

Tags: excel, vb6

I am playing around with some code that may allow a hidden instance of an excel application to be created and remain hidden and running. I wanted to run a quick check to find these and close them.

I came up with the following code which doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
For Each xl In Applications
If xl.Visible = False Then xl.Quit
Next
```

Comment: How are you checking for them? Are you using VBA in Excel, or VBScript, or a VB.NET app?

Comment: VB6 IDE -- answer needs to be longer so I am saying randomneess

Comment: So are you using VB6 and accessing Excel library via Interop? Also, please clarify what you mean by "it doesn't work"

Comment: xlApp As Excel.Application

Comment: project references microsoft excel 14.0 object library

Comment: it doesn't work means it gives error instead of closing excel applications open in memory. I can control + alt+ delete to view task manager and see loads of Excel.exe *32 open. I need to close all of them

Comment: Could you not iterate *processes* instead, and kill any that involves EXCEL.EXE?

Comment: no because I only want to quit hidden excel iterations. user could have their own Excel iteration open and I don't want to accidentally kill that.

Comment: Do you have a COM add-in installed in Excel? Try looking for "excel ghost process", your `Application` instance is probably indeed terminated, what's not terminated is the *process* that hosted it, because *something* is still alive in that process space - and that's at a lower level than the `Excel.Application` one.

Comment: How are you starting the Excel application? If you're instantiating a new Excel applications, are you not keeping track of them? Maybe you should edit the question to show the where you start the Excel application.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, BEFORE instantiating a new excel application, iterate to all current processes containing "EXCEL.EXE", store the process ids, create you new instance of the Excel application, iterate again (there should be one more process with "EXCEL.EXE"), then you have the process id to kill after .. not an elegant solution, but works for killing your zombie processes